# There was an error in the working CMS and I can not even enter to management panel

Tags: typo3, typo3-extensions

There was an error in the working CMS and I can not even enter management panel. I did not update PHP on the server, nothing changed in the configuration, and yet I can't enter the administration panel or display the WWW page.

When I try to get on administration panel or on website there is a message like this:

PHP Runtime Notice: Declaration of tx_ttnews_catmenu::wrapTitle() should be compatible with t3lib_treeView::wrapTitle($title, $row, $bank = 0) in /home2/izbampro/public_html/typo3/typo3conf/ext/tt_news/class.tx_ttnews_catmenu.php line 56

Is this a bug related to a too old version of PHP, or could someone break into the server and change the configuration?I have no idea what could have happened, everything worked well several days ago. Please help me with this error.

Comment: As you can see `t3lib_treeView::wrapTitle($title, $row, $bank = 0)` accept parameter while `tx_ttnews_catmenu::wrapTitle()` does not pass any parameter. This means that both declarations are incompatible and while the implemented interface must be satisfied PHP throws the shown error.

Comment: Ok, so I need to update PHP to fix this error?

Comment: Which versions of PHP, TYPO3 and the extension tt_news are you running?

Comment: PHP 5.6.26, typo3 and tt_news I don`t know...Where I can check this when I can`t get into administration panel?

Comment: You can see the TYPO3 version when you go to "About" => "Modules". Or open the TYPO3 Install Tool. Third possibility: have a look at `typo3/sysext/core/ext_emconf.php`. The version of tt_news can be seen in the Extension Manager. Or have a look into the file `typo3conf/ext/tt_news/ext_emconf.php`.

Answer (score 0):

what do you mean with the `administration panel`?

- in TYPO3 you have the `BackEnd` where you can do the normal administration and editorial tasks.
  it is called normally with `domain.tld/typo3/`
- the other area for administrative tasks is the `Install Tool`
  which is called with `domain.tld/typo3/install/`

While the `Backend`needs a running TYPO3 instance the `InstallTool` should be callable even if there is no configuration (e.g. database).

regarding your TYPO3 version:
we can guess a little bit with your data:
PHP 5.6.26 will let run TYPO3 only until version 7.6
the function reference `t3lib_treeView::wrapTitle` will restrict the version in the same way as the classname was available in core up to 4.7. for later version there existed an compatibility extension, first in core, later from TER.

if you have a look onto your server we might have further restrictions.
I will not exclude the usage of older versions up to 4.7:
these versions can be identified by files `typo3conf/localconf.php`, while since 6.0 the files are named `typo3conf/LocalConfiguration.php`.

In the same way there is a break in the storing which extensions are active in your installation:
up to 4.7 it was one line in `typo3conf/localconf.php`, since 6.0 it is an own file `typo3conf/PackageStates.php`.

You should be able to call the install tool, which will show the version (a screenshot from the appearance after the Install Tool login might help. But first we need to make you accessing the Install Tool.

**Are you able to login to the install tool?**
the TYPO3 version will decide about the next steps